# Horizontal menu in apex

Tags: menu, oracle-apex

I'm learning oracle apex and I want to create system ( for my training ) where learners can check their grades. I'm making page which shows grades from only one school subject. So above the report I would like to have list of all school subjects and upon clicking one value from the list the report should  change.  ( to this point I'm able to do it ). I want my list to look like "region display" selector ( or something similar). I just want values to be next to each other not one under another ). I tried all templates for lists but all are vertical. Is there a way to do this?

EDIT: I managed to deal with this problem. The resolution is:

- select dynamic list region
- go to attributes-->list template
- choose navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create one region for each subject and then display a Region Display Selector above the first subject.
Then as the students selects a different subject that region is displayed and the previous subject is hidden.

Regards,
David

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i was thinkig of something created dynamically. I didn`t write it in my question but i want items of the list to be result of sql query